# NonExistentTimeError when localizing pandas datetime index

Tags: python, django, pandas, timezone

I am using `dataframe.index = dataframe.index.tz_localize('Iran')` to localize my Pandas dataframe datetime index. The problem is Django rises a `NonExistentTimeError`.

Django `setting.py` timezone is setted to my local time zone. `TIME_ZONE = 'Iran'`

Dataframe:

```
2014-08-11 12:00:00+00:00  3076.366
2014-08-11 11:45:00+00:00  3076.367
2014-08-11 11:30:00+00:00  3076.385
2014-08-11 11:15:00+00:00  3076.417
2014-08-11 11:00:00+00:00  3076.466
2014-08-11 10:45:00+00:00  3076.532
2014-08-11 10:30:00+00:00  3076.611
2014-08-11 10:15:00+00:00  3076.702
2014-08-11 10:00:00+00:00  3076.802
2014-08-11 09:45:00+00:00  3076.910

In [112]:dataframe.index.tzinfo
In [113]:<StaticTzInfo 'GMT'>
```

[10 rows x 1 columns]

Comment: related: [Creation of datetimeindex for east coast fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69288855/10197418)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exception `NonExistentTimeError` is raised from [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) when you attempt to localize a `datetime` that doesn't exist in the time zone you specified.

If you're wondering how time can "not exist", consider that local time in many time zones is affected by [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dst).  It is also occasionally affected by changes made by local governments.

In your particular case, all of the values you showed were on August 11, 2014.  Iran's daylight saving time fall-back transition doesn't occur until September 21, 2014, [as shown here](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/iran/tehran?year=2014).  If one of your values was `2014-09-21 11:30:00`, then it would make sense.   I can only conclude that you didn't show the actual data that caused the error.  Please check your data.

Also, you should be using the full time zone name, which is `'Asia/Tehran'`.  While `'Iran'` may work now, it is a backwards compatibility link only, and you should use the canonical zone name instead.  See also [this list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: Thank's for your help [Daylight saving time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dst) helped me to solve problem