# Pandas date time formatting with timezone shifting

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timezone

I have a sqlite database where each row has a unix timestamp in EST.  Changing this is not possible.  I put this data into a pandas data frame.

I am running a script on a server that is on UTC and when I convert the EST timestamps to date time objects I am unable to capture the full day of EST time because it is shifted 4 hours forward like so:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.date
```

Is there way to do timezone shifting in pandas so that date time objects are created based on EST unix time?

Comment: For clarification, are your timestamps in EST or in UTC once you've constructed the DataFrame? Also do you really intended for the `time` column to simply be a *date*?

Comment: @chrisaycock The timestamps are in EST once I've constructed the dataframe.  I think the problem arises because I am creating data time objects on a UTC system, so for example the date of 6/9/15 has a different full set of ETC and UTC timestamps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The middle line is how I've converted timezones in pandas:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
df = df.set_index('time').tz_localize('US/Eastern').tz_convert('UTC').tz_convert(None).reset_index()
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.date
```

Comment: Thanks.  This will still work if my time column is not an index, correct?  As my code stands now it is not an index and I would need to make a ton of changes if it were the index.

Comment: @Meter All the examples and documentation I've read for `tz_convert()` requires an index. It's really annoying, as you've experienced.

Comment: To do this conversion, I had to get exclude `tz_convert(None)` from your conversion statement.

Comment: Just to make clear: The source time currently in the dataframe is `tz_localize('US/Eastern')`, the destionation (convertion goal) is `tz_convert('UTC')`.

Comment: Remember that a `NonExistentTimeError` could be thrown if the time doesn't exists in both time zones. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25271265/2056125