# Creation of datetimeindex for east coast fails with NonExistentTimeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timezone

I am trying to do something very simple and I am really confused with the error. I am trying to create a DateTimeIndex in pandas which is aware of the time zone. This works well when I do it for west coast, but fails for east coast which doesn't make any sense.

Here is what I tried so far:

In approach-1 shown below, index_1 gets created well, however index_2 fails.

#### Approach - 1

```
import pandas as pd

time_zone_1 = 'America/Phoenix'
time_zone_2 = 'America/New_York'

index_1= pd.DatetimeIndex(
    data=pd.date_range(start='1990-01-01 01:00', freq='H', periods=8759),
    tz=time_zone_1
)

index_2= pd.DatetimeIndex(
    data=pd.date_range(start='1990-01-01 01:00', freq='H', periods=8759),
    tz=time_zone_2
)
```

Alternatively, borrowing directly from pandas documentation:

#### Approach - 2

```
import pandas as pd 
tz_naive = pd.date_range('1990-01-01 01:00', periods=8759)
tz_aware = tz_naive.tz_localize(tz='US/Eastern')
```

#### Approach - 3

Since the dates are sequential, I tried to use the ambiguous flag and set it to infer, but that still doesn't solve the problem

```
import pandas as pd 
tz_naive = pd.date_range('1990-01-01 01:00', periods=8759)
tz_aware = tz_naive.tz_localize(tz='US/Eastern', ambiguous='infer')
```

Can someone point to what I could be doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I think this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266675/nonexistenttimeerror-when-localizing-pandas-datetime-index

Comment: Muhammad, 
Thank you for that. In approach-2 and approach-3 mentioned above, I am attempting to remedy the same, where in I am using the ambiguous flag to try and force pandas to infer the timestamp where it runs into trouble. But that is not helping either

Comment: @UGuntupalli if you include the parameter `tz` in the `date_range` instead of in the `DatetimeIndex` like you do here, it works I think

Comment: and it does not fail with Phoenix because in 1990 (maybe still true today), there seems to be no time saving in Phoenix-Arizona

Comment: While I understand that it works in Phoenix because there is no day light savings, there should be a way this should work in DST locations as well. I am hoping someone knows how to achieve that. None of approaches 1, 2 or 3 have worked for me so far

Comment: @UGuntupalli did you try with the tz in the date_range? like `index_2= pd.date_range(start='1990-01-01 01:00', freq='H', periods=8759, tz='America/New_York')`?

Comment: @Ben.T, 
Yes. Still doesn't work